# Keep customer's private data even from the developer (me)

Tags: database, database-design, storage, privacy

I am developing a service for my school students that needs a non-hashed private data storage (locational data, school credentials, et cetra), but I need a way to show that even I, the developer, isn't doing anything fishy with their data. Is there any way to acheive this?

Comment: Some database engines provide encryption and decryption services.

Answer (score 0):

This is far too vague a question for SO, so here's a vague answer.

Generate keys on your clients, and encrypt data on the client side, in-browser. That way you can blindly store whatever data they like, and you will have no access to it. Of course if they lose their key, all their data will be irretrievable.